# d3 multi line alignment with y axis data

Tags: d3.js

I have created the d3 Multi-line chart. I managed to generate both **x** and **y** **axis** along with the **Lines**. But unfortunately i got stuck at this point where I am not able to align the **Path-lines** with the Y axis i.e. `ScaleBand()`.  I have no idea how do to that and guide line for that would be great. I have attached my code with sample data in snippet. Thanks in advance.

```js
var dataDomains = ['automated', 'manual']
var data = [
    { automated: 1000 , manual: 3000 },
    { automated: 5000 , manual: 6000 },
    { automated: 10000, manual: 9000 },
    { automated: 50000, manual: 12000 },
    { automated: 100000, manual: 15000 },
]


// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
        var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


        // set the ranges
        var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scaleBand().range([height, 0]);

        // define the 1st line
        var valueline = d3.line()
            .x(function (d) { return x(d.automated); })
            .y(function (d) { return y('automated'); });

        // define the 2nd line
        var valueline2 = d3.line()
            .x(function (d) { return x(d.manual); })
            .y(function (d) { return y('manual'); });

        // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
        // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
        // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
        var svg = d3.select("#cl-AVM").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // Scale the range of the data
        x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return Math.max(d.automated, d.manual) })])
        y.domain(dataDomains);

        // Add the valueline path.
        svg.append("path")
            .data([data])
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline);

        // Add the valueline2 path.
        svg.append("path")
            .data([data])
            .attr("class", "line")
            .style("stroke", "red")
            .attr("d", valueline2);

        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

        // Add the Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

```css
       .line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="cl-AVM"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a scalePoint instead of a scaleBand as your line can be considered as just a point on the y axis.

Then you can add some padding so that the values for the two points are not 0 and 100 (I picked 0.6 but you can play around with it and see what best suits you).

You can see usage of scalePoint here in more details: https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-scalepoint

Hope that helps ! :)

```js
var dataDomains = ['automated', 'manual']
var data = [
    { automated: 1000 , manual: 3000 },
    { automated: 5000 , manual: 6000 },
    { automated: 10000, manual: 9000 },
    { automated: 50000, manual: 12000 },
    { automated: 100000, manual: 15000 },
]


// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
        var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


        // set the ranges
        var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scalePoint().range([height, 0]).padding(0.6); // modified here

        // define the 1st line
        var valueline = d3.line()
            .x(function (d) { return x(d.automated); })
            .y(function (d) { return y('automated'); });

        // define the 2nd line
        var valueline2 = d3.line()
            .x(function (d) { return x(d.manual); })
            .y(function (d) { return y('manual'); });

        // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
        // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
        // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
        var svg = d3.select("#cl-AVM").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // Scale the range of the data
        x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return Math.max(d.automated, d.manual) })])
        y.domain(dataDomains);
        
        // Add the valueline path.
        svg.append("path")
            .data([data])
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline);

        // Add the valueline2 path.
        svg.append("path")
            .data([data])
            .attr("class", "line")
            .style("stroke", "red")
            .attr("d", valueline2);

        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

        // Add the Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

```css
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="cl-AVM"></div>
```

Comment: I also have a interactive demo here (https://observablehq.com/@remi-sanchez/point-scales-d3-scalepoint) for scalePoint if it can help you visualize how the parameters modify the display !

Comment: Thank you. Yes this help fixes the problem. But i found another way also  i.e. adding back the removed margin in `d3.Line().y(function (d) { return yScale('automated') + margin.top; })`

Comment: Ah yes that might work for certain values of margin.top, but take care as this might not always be the case depending on the height of your graph or the parameters of your scaleBand (like paddingInner and outer).
ScaleBand assume objects will have some "width" (like the bars of a bar chart for example so that's what's causing the line to not be aligned with the label, when they don't have the width of the band).
Anyway, glad you found solutions :)